# How to update size on View element on click of a Button in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm new in React Native programming and wanted to ask how to change View size on a button click. In other words, how to change it dynamically.

This is the View element:

```
<View
    style={{ height: 350, alignSelf: "stretch", margin: 10 }}
/>
```

My goal is, on some button click, this `height: 350` to be changed, for example, to `height: 450`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first keep a value in your state, then update it with the button click.

for an example:

```
 this.state = {
      height: 350, //your initial value
  };
```

> and set your value in button click function

```
onButtonClick = () => {
    this.setState({height: 450});
 };
```

set this value to your view

```
<View style={{ height: this.state.height, alignSelf: "stretch", margin: 10 }}
/>
```

that's all..
happy coding..!

Comment: Thank you very much :)